# reporting website templates

Tags: html, templates, reporting

I am starting my work to develop an intranet reporting website in php and html. I wanted to know if there are any templates for page layout, so that i can quickly select the look of the page and then start all my coding for the reporting system. i would really appreciate if anyone could help me with few links.

ofcourse, i am looking for free templates only, because i am using it only for page layout. not willing to pay for this. Else if there is already a free reporting website which can be changed according to my needs then I would appreciate that. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

I've used this with success:  http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/layout/

It's not a full-blown layout like you might expect, but it overcomes a common design pattern flaw that causes HTML and CSS to overrun the screen when some sort of vertical menu is put on the left side.  Resizing is a great plus, and the CSS reset makes IE flaws virtually a thing of the past.

Here's a semi-ugly example of what it can do:  http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/examples/layout/adv_layout_source.html

Related to this, I can't say enough about Jquery Datatables (http://datatables.net/) for the functionality it brings to plain tabular data such as sorting, filtering, paging, show/hide detail, etc.  My company's report site immediately moved to a new level thanks to datatables and themeroller.